# Is there a way to rebuild AnimatedList in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have the following issue with my 'workout' App using multiple *workoutlists* with various *workoutitems*:

I select a *workoutlist* with 12 *workoutitems*.
The 'activity' screen with the AnimatedList is shown.
Afterwards, I select a different *workoutlist* with 80 *workoutitems*.
The AnimatedList is now showing the new *workoutlist* but only the first 12 *workoutitems*.
Why?

I thought that the AnimatedList inside the build Widget is rebuild every time (I am not using GlobalKey).

```
class WorkoutListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const WorkoutListView({this.filename});
  final String filename;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Selector<WorkoutListModel, List<Workout>>(
      selector: (_, model) => model.filterWorkouts(filename),
      builder: (context, workouts, _) {
        return AnimatedWorkoutList(
            list: workouts,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedWorkoutList extends StatefulWidget {
 const AnimatedWorkoutList({
    Key key,
    @required List<Workout> list,
  })  : _list = list,
        super(key: key);  
  final List<Workout> _list;

  @override
  _AnimatedWorkoutListState createState() => _AnimatedWorkoutListState();
}

class _AnimatedWorkoutListState extends State<AnimatedWorkoutList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedList(
      initialItemCount: widget._list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
        final workout = widget._list[index];
        return Column(
          children: [
         // Using AnimatedList.of(context).removeItem() for list manipulation
         ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class AnimatedWorkoutList extends StatefulWidget {
 const AnimatedWorkoutList({
    @required List<Workout> list,
  });  
  final List<Workout> list;

  @override
  _AnimatedWorkoutListState createState() => _AnimatedWorkoutListState();
}

class _AnimatedWorkoutListState extends State<AnimatedWorkoutList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedList(
      initialItemCount: widget.list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
        final workout = widget.list[index];
        return Column(
          children: [
         // Using AnimatedList.of(context).removeItem() for list manipulation
         ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Unfortunately, this is not solving the issue.